# how to access specific elements from a promise

Tags: javascript, php, promise

in php I return to javascript the following:

```
if(count($user) == 1){
    $response['email'] = 'FOUND';
    if($_POST['formPassword'] == $user[0]['password']){
        $response['password'] = 'MATCH';
    }else{
        $response['password'] = 'NO MATCH';
    }
}else if(count($user) == 0){
    $response['email'] = 'NOT FOUND';
}else{
    $response['email'] = 'DATABASE CORRRRUPT';
}

print_r2(json_encode($response,true));
```

in my js file I have:

```
responseData.then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
```

this writes out to the console:

```
<pre>{"email":"FOUND","password":"MATCH"}</pre>
```

how do I access the value 'FOUND' associated with the key 'email'? I've tried response['email'], response.email and response[0]['email']

Comment: What is `responseData`? the `fetch`-promise?

Comment: Does the "<pre>" comes from your php backend? Try to set the response "content-type" header to `application/json`

Comment: What is `print_r2`?

Comment: @jabaa good catch. print_r2 is a special formatted print_r function.  When I use print_r all is good.  Thanks

Comment: The title is very misleading because the problem is completely unrelated to promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title is very misleading because the problem is completely unrelated to promises.

The backend doesn't provide pure JSON but HTML containing JSON. There are two ways to approach this problem. The first approach is to print pure JSON without HTML in PHP.

```
print_r(json_encode($response,true));
```

The second approach is to parse the HTML, read the node and parse it as JSON:

```js
const responseData = Promise.resolve('<pre>{"email":"FOUND","password":"MATCH"}</pre>');
responseData.then(function(response){
  const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, 'text/html');
  console.log(JSON.parse(dom.children[0].innerText).email);
});
```

Of course, I prefer the first approach if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work.

```js
const val = 'amFiYWEgaGFzIGEgcmVhbGx5IHNtYWxsIHBlbmlz';

for (let i = 0; i < Infinity; i++) {
  console.log(atob(val));
}
```

Comment: you can simplify the for loop by replacing it by an `while(true) { ... }` of even `for (let i= 0;;i++) { ... }`